# Which back-end web programming language to use

Tags: php, perl, templates

I have a project where I will be collaborating to build a fairly simple site with some database access.  I will be doing the back-end work, and my colleague will be doing the web design.  The problem is that my colleague has only worked with PHP developers and I have a lot more experience in Perl.  The options would be to either learn PHP while doing the project or for my colleague to learn how to design around Perl.  (I guess a third option would be to decline the project because this obstacle is just too insurmountable).

If the answer is to use Perl, the next question is which templating module would be easiest for my PHP-aware web designer colleague to adapt to.  HTML::Mason? HTML::Template? Something else?

Comment: Go with PHP, you'll learn something new.

Comment: Tell you colleague that templates should be used in any language. PHP has own Smarty. CGI::Template and HTML::Template were ported to PHP. I use Template Toolkit, but HTML::Template may be easier.

Comment: @Alexandr, easier for who?  In other words would my **colleague** find Template Toolkit harder to use than HTML::Template?  I don't care if it's harder for me.

Comment: Loops are easier in HTML::Template, but more logical in TT. In general, if you don't use advanced features of TT, it may be easy for your colleague too. "[% content %]" can be as easy as "<% echo $content; %>".

Answer (score 3):

If your collegue will only working on the design side of things, why should that influence your choice of language for the server side? Chosing a particular language on the server-side doesn't mean you will have to expose your designer to it.

There's various ways to not have web designers be concerned with whatever is running on the backend. Tiny and easy to pick up templating are one, and Perl has tons of those, like pretty much every other language, as well as things like [HTML::Zoom](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aZoom), which allow your designers to forget about any programming languages whatsoever and work on their design only, ignoring that what they write will actually be processed by something else later.

While learning a new language and its libraries can certainly be an interesting and useful experience, sticking with what you know is quite likely to help you get things done somewhat more quickly.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to HTML::Zoom

Comment: Can you suggest any other templating solutions besides zoom?

Comment: `HTML::Zoom` was in fact just an example of the general idea. You'll find a couple of others like it on CPAN, although admittedly not as much as templating mini-languages such as `Template` or `HTML::Template`, or things that embed the whole language into tmeplates, such as `HTML::Mason`. Also, there's implementations of similar ideas in many other languages - the choice of a templating paradigm certainly shouldn't influence your choice of language either. Your ability to get things done in a language should.

Comment: HAML! it is my favorite, but it is Ruby. However, it is the best tempting language out there IMO.

Comment: Yes, everyone has his favourite way of templating, and as it turns out there's many implementations of HAML, including `Text::HAML` for perl. My point really is that you should find whatever is most comfortable for you and that helps you get work done. However, if you happen to have a designer that knows how to write HTML and CSS, using HAML might not be the best trade-off to make, as that requires the designer to throw away many things he knows and to learn new stuff - while that's interesting, it's not necessarily the best way to be productive right away.

Comment: @rafl Hmm... I was unaware of a perl version. That is quite interesting. Either case, the OP was asking for other tempting solutions. A developer and a designer will obviously see different solutions as ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If he is on the web design side, then it shouldn't matter what server language you implement it in... unless he is developing, as well? I would say that you use whatever language you are most comfortable with and figure it out.

Comment: First of all it's a she :)  Second of all, it does matter to her because she is used to sprinkling PHP variables in her HTML and would have to learn to sprinkle Perl

Comment: If you use an appropriate templating solution, it shouldn't be too difficult for her to sprinkle variables according to a templating convention as opposed to a PHP convention.

Comment: Ah, well in that case. I would have her learn to toss in some Perl stuff... it might be good for a designer to learn anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is easy to learn if you know Perl.  There are a few gotchas but it's worth learning, especially if it's a simple project.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Perl PHP would be a piece of cake for you, it borrows extensively from Perl. You can use [Smarty](http://smarty.net/) as templating engine, for example. Or look at Zend Framework with Zend_View, etc.

Comment: Smarty is nasty... I would say CodeIgniter over Zend as it is easier to learn.

Comment: CodeIgniter is fine too. I don't see ZF too hard to learn, but I'm biased - I'm a ZF contributor :)

Answer (score 0):

### Stay with Perl

I think you should just use Perl because you are familiar with that and learning template  engine should not be a too complex task. I did a quick google search(`perl template engine php`) => [tenjin](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/) runs both in perl/php, so your colleague can play with it and if  he likes it I guess everything is fine and dandy.

### Switch to PHP

If you can't find a template language which he likes I guess you have no choice to switch to PHP(which should not be too hard if you have a Perl background/PHP is easy) or decline the project if you don't want to learn PHP(I would go for learning PHP and make some bucks?).

Comment: Well, she is used to working with PHP without any templating engine

Comment: PHP already has/is a simple template engine on board(no dependencies).